# Bootstrap toggle-collapse expands my navbar menu but won't collapse it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

"Bootstrap toggle-collapse expands my navbar menu but won't collapse it."

I've tried messing with the classes and data-target and adding extra script to no avail. The menu expands, then when toggled again it sometimes appears to flicker like it drops down and is immediately open again but most of the time nothing seems to happen. In the Chrome inspector aria=true never becomes false. It appears like it would change but always remains true.

My scripts are located in a separate layout file but they are working. All other functionality works and this even works halfway.

Here's the current code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">

        <a href="#" class="navbar-toggle"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></a>

        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="#navbar">
            <span class="fa fa-bars"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ path('homepage') }}"><img src="{{ asset('img/logo-blue.png') }}" alt="Podify" /></a>
    </div>

    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse" role="navigation">

        {{ mopa_bootstrap_menu('AppBundle:Builder:mainMenu', { 'automenu': 'navbar' }) }}
        <!--
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="/features">Features <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#pricing">Pricing <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#contact">Contact <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        </ul>
        -->
        <ul class="nav navbar-right nav-pills hidden-xs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i> Login</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Join</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
</div>
```

My code doesn't show the nav tag closed for some reason here but i see it when editing my post.

I imagine it's something simple i'm overlooking. Any help will of course be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Make sure you include jequery, bootstrap.js, bootstrap.css

Comment: thanks, should mention that in the post. all scripts and stylesheets are included. i wouldn't get the expand functionality otherwise.

Comment: Just add class 'navbar-default' after navbar class in nav, And you forgot to close nav tag.

Comment: my code actually has the closed nav tag but it wont appear here for some reason (i see it when editing my post). i tried adding 'navbar-default' which added some interesting styling to my navbar but otherwise did not affect the issue at hand. thanks for the help though.

Comment: @ZakKarst Please include all the scripts you are using. It's hard to help you with an incomplete picture of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

this Jquery enables Toggle functionality.